# benifits/drawbacks of returning a const or final value/reference from any method

Tags: c, constants, return-type

I am a novice programmer exploring the depths of C. Why does some inbuilt functions return a const value ? Can somebody explain the benefits or drawbacks of using const in method returns ?

Comment: Java and C are very different languages following very different language philosophies. Java's `final` is used very differently C's `const`, and it's probably dangerous to compare the two as a novice.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. While the OP incorrectly conflates `const` and `final`, the question is asking about their difference and I think the answers are important because they show how the OP is incorrect. I think this is useful for people who may have made the same mistake. The linked question only talks about `const` in C.

Answer (score 0):

Using final and const in returning values from functions and methods is to keep people from changing their values. For example, if i had (in c)

```
char* getChar()
{
   return "string";
}
```

and I didn't want someone to use it like

```
char myChar = getChar()[0]++;
```

then i would have to return a const, to keep it from being changed.

For Java, it's *very* different. You don't **return** final values, you make **methods** final.

`final` is used with a Java method to mark that the method can't be overridden (for object scope) or hidden (for static). This allows the original developer to create functionality that he can be sure will not be changed by others, and that is all the guarantee it provides.

Comment: Don't forget you can also make variables final.

Comment: @DJClayworth yup! But OP was just asking about method/function returns i believe.

Comment: In that C example, you'd still be returning a non-const value, it's just that that value would be a pointer to a const char.

Answer (score 0):

C's `const` and Java's `final` are very different, and especially in the case you're talking about.

In C (disclaimer: I haven't done C in a while so please let me know where I'm wrong) let's look at this example:

```
const int something() {
    return 3;
}
```

The `const` is meaningless because it's not like you can do:

```
something() = 3;
```

For some more information on `const` return values in C, take a look at the following:

- [`const` makes no sense for return values...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541784/263004)
- [Purpose of returning by const value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) (this is C++, but still useful).

In Java, I'm assuming you're talking about something like:

```
public final int something() {
    ...
}
```

Here `final` has nothing to do with the return value. `final` here means that if you extend the class that `something()` belongs to, you cannot override the implementation of `something()`. This is somewhat similar in spirit to `final` variables; these are variables whose values you cannot change once they are set.