# What are the uses of making a C function's return type as const?

Tags: c, constants, return-type

I need to know the advantages that a programmer has by making a function return type as 'const' qualified in C. This question is not related to C++.

Following function signature is a valid C function signature, so the creators allowed it keeping some use case in mind, which I cannot find anywhere in web.

```
const int foo(int arg);
```

I know in C++ it has a lot of uses to make returned objects immutable or read-only because there can be accidental assignments to returned object.

Comment: The language allows you to have a `const` in the return type, because *sometimes* this is useful. Sometimes it is not, but there is no language rule forbidding the less useful cases. And it does no harm.

Answer (score 4):

`const` makes no sense for return values because return values are *rvalues* in any case and can't be modified.

[Src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541784/2411320).

---

An exception: `const T*` can be useful, since it mentions that the object the pointer is pointing to is constant, and the user of the function should respect that.

Answer (score -3):

Consider the following case:

```
const char* F() {
    return " aaaaaaaaa. Ddddd";
}
```

Comment: Might be a bit late, but... that does not at all address the question. The return type is a non-const pointer. The data where it points to is const. That does not make it a const return value.